# multipart/mixed decryption on blackberry 10

Tags: mime-types, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am writing an app that decrypts encrypted emails for a client.

The encrypted data is in the form of an email attachment, which, when decrypted, looks like this :

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="PGP_Universal_830ECF7A_AFB087B4_241DE401_9BE7FFD1"

--PGP_Universal_830ECF7A_AFB087B4_241DE401_9BE7FFD1
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="PGP_Universal_904F5C3F_3A8C9E07_A3A24D11_F0FB260C"

--PGP_Universal_904F5C3F_3A8C9E07_A3A24D11_F0FB260C
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT

 [snip]

--PGP_Universal_904F5C3F_3A8C9E07_A3A24D11_F0FB260C
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: QUOTED-PRINTABLE

[html content]



--PGP_Universal_904F5C3F_3A8C9E07_A3A24D11_F0FB260C--
--PGP_Universal_830ECF7A_AFB087B4_241DE401_9BE7FFD1
Content-Type: application/pdf;
name="BB_FW_60_Manual_Key.Enrollment_Final_v1.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="BB_FW_60_Manual_Key.Enrollment_Final_v1.pdf"

[base64 data]

--PGP_Universal_830ECF7A_AFB087B4_241DE401_9BE7FFD1--
```

I am writing the app in Cascades. As I cannot find a native way of transforming this data into an email, to let the email client deal with the attached base64-encoded file and so on,  I am hoping to find a C++ class (it can optionally depend upon Qt, obviously) that I can use on the BB10 which can parse these kind of multipart messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get SPMIME to compile on BB10. It is LGPL so it might need to be compiled seperately and linked to if your app is not GPL.